# Error in UITabel connected to SQlite3

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite

I connected Sqlite3 to my project to UITableview the code went fine But when i open the table in simulator instead of data it is showing something like `<db: 0x8a35e20>`.
Can anyone let me know what went wrong !

Please find my code of table below:

```
#import "table1.h"
#import "db.h"

@implementation table1
@synthesize tableOne;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    databaseName=@"nobel10.db";

    NSArray *documentPaths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath=[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [self readDataFromDatabase];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


#pragma mark - TableView Data Source methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [tableOne count]; }

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell= nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"mycell"];}
    cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,[tableOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return  cell;}
-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(success)
        return;

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
    [fileManager release];
}
-(void)readDataFromDatabase{
    sqlite3 *database;
    tableOne=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)== SQLITE_OK){
    const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM gender";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *stringName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

                db *info =[[db alloc]initWithName:stringName];
                [tableOne addObject:info];
                [info release];
            }

        }
         sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
- (void)dealloc
{

    [tableOne release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Retain tableOne after [tableOne addObject:info];

Comment: NSLog after NSString *stringName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

Comment: hi Sara it is not printing any thing just shows 0,0

Comment: Its Sarah, Also That is where your problem occurs. Try some good tutorial and implement the same thing in a better way.

Comment: Check this site. It has good tutorials for newbies... http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

Comment: can please suggest some tutorial

Comment: I have already suggested one in my post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly setting the db object to the tableview's label.You may need to set the db object's instance variables value to the label as follows

```
cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,[(db*)[tableOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name]];
```

Comment: Hi Monish.. if i follow this code it is showing error as// Thread1:Program received signal"EXC_BAD_ACCESS"